# Summation of binomial number of poisson random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Z is summation of *K* random variables that each has Poisson distribution with different means. But, *K* is a Binomial random with parameters of *n* and *p*.

I was wondering what is the distribution of Z?

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, but it does not look like a famous distribution like Poisson. I was wondering if it is Poisson or not.

Comment: It seems unlikely that there is a simple description of the distribution of the sum.  Can it be considered as $n$ Poission random variables with different means, but you only include each one in the sum independently with probability $p$?  If so, you can calculate the mean and variance of the sum.

Comment: If $K$ is Binomial, then $K=0$ is a possible outcome. Is that your intention? i.e. do you want to allow for a sum of zero random variables? Or did you intend that there was at least 1 random variable in the sum?

Comment: @Henry : Yes. What about estimating binomial with poisson? Does it simplify the distribution for Z?

Comment: @wolfies : Yes, K could be 0 too. However, assuming that there is at least 1 random variable in the sum changes any thing?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt $Z$ has a simple distribution.  But it might be possible to describe its moments.

For example if you have a random variable $X_i$ with a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda_i$ then its variance is also $\lambda_i$ and its second moment is $\lambda_i+\lambda_i^2$.  So if you have a random variable $Y_i$ which is $X_i$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$, the mean of $Y_i$ is $p\lambda_i$, its second moment is $p\lambda_i+p\lambda_i^2$ and its variance is $p\lambda_i+p\lambda_i^2 - p^2\lambda_i^2$.

So taking $Z$ to be the sum of $n$ such independent $Y_i$s, the mean of $Z$ is $$E[Z]=\sum_{i=1}^n p\lambda_i$$ and the variance of $Z$ is $$\text{Var}(Z) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(p\lambda_i+p\lambda_i^2 - p^2\lambda_i^2\right)$$ so the second moment is $$E[X^2] = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(p\lambda_i+p\lambda_i^2 - p^2\lambda_i^2\right) + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n p\lambda_i\right)^2$$  and you might with some effort extend this to higher moments.  Since the variance is larger than the mean, this does not have a Poisson distribution.

You can also calculate the probability that 
$$\Pr(Z=0)=\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-p+pe^{-\lambda_i}\right)$$ and $$\Pr(Z=1)=p \left(\sum_{j=1}^n  \frac{ \lambda_j e^{-\lambda_j}}{1-p+pe^{-\lambda_j}}\right) \left(\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-p+pe^{-\lambda_i}\right)\right)$$ but I suspect higher values of $Z$ are harder.